# Wireshark PCAP file to csv

Tags: python, wireshark, scapy

Looking for an module in python which could read PCAP file and write it to csv format.
Have explored pyshark module - unable to get output in required form

```
capture = pyshark.FileCapture(r"C:\Temp\wireshark\data.pcap")
for pkt in capture:
    pkt = str(pkt)
    out.write(pkt)
```

Answer (score 1):

try module `rdpcap`

read here for more info - https://medium.com/@vworri/extracting-the-payload-from-a-pcap-file-using-python-d938d7622d71

```
pkts = rdpcap('example.pcap')

with open("Pcap/test.csv", "w") as f:
    for pkt in pkts:

        if IP in pkt:
            ip_src=pkt[IP].src
            ip_dst=pkt[IP].dst
        if TCP in pkt:
            tcp_dport=pkt[TCP].dport

            csv_header = "IP_src,IP_drc,dst_port\n"

            s = ""
            for scr in str(ip_src):
                s+=str(scr)
            csv_header += s + ','

            s_ = ''
            for dst in str(ip_dst) :
                s_+=str(dst)
            csv_header += s_ + ','

            s_1 = ''
            for dst_tcp in str(tcp_dport):
                s_1 += str(dst_tcp)
            csv_header += s_1

            f.write(csv_header)
```